# Downloading whole HTML document as a PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tsx

I tried download a specific html document via [html2PDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-html2canvas) function in a React app.
Here it's my code:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState }      from "react";
import { Grid, CircularProgress }                             from "@material-ui/core";
import { getUserExamResult }                                  from "@containers/dashboard/users/websiteUsers/tools/api";
import html2PDF                                               from "jspdf-html2canvas";

export interface UserExamFullResultProps {
    data: any;
}

const UserExamFullResult: FunctionComponent<UserExamFullResultProps> = ({
    data,
}) => {
    const [examResultHtml, setExamResultHtml] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                const result = await getUserExamResult(
                    data?.userProfileId,
                    data?.examId,
                    {}
                );
                setExamResultHtml(result?.resultPage);
            } catch (err) {}
        })();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const targetElement = document.getElementById("exam-result");
        if (targetElement) {
            targetElement.innerHTML = examResultHtml;
        }
    }, [examResultHtml]);

const handleExamResultDownload = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById("exam-result");

    html2PDF(element, {
        jsPDF: {
            format: "a4",
        },
        imageType: "image/jpeg",
        output: "./pdf/generate.pdf",
    });
};

    return (
        <>
            {examResultHtml ? (
            <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center">
                <Tooltip color="action" title="دانلود نتیجه‌ی کامل" placement="right">
                    <IconButton onClick={handleExamResultDownload}>
                        <GetApp/>
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
                <div id="exam-result"></div>
            </Grid>
            ) : (
                <Grid
                    style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }}
                    container
                    justify="center"
                    alignItems="center"
                >
                    <Grid item style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <CircularProgress />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default UserExamFullResult;
```

The specific HTML document that I mentioned before comes from an API and shown in [this link](https://www.scribd.com/document/483712440/Document), and a corrupted output PDF file shown on [this link](https://www.scribd.com/document/483699371/PDF-Generate-1). As you can see, the PDF file images didn't load and paging is not suitable.

Comment: Scribd is a terrible place to host documents. That aside, it looks like that API is taking steps to prevent hot-linking. Since your app is unlikely to be on the same domain as the API, it may not be able to load the images.

Comment: @Ouroborus Ok, and, how can I resolve the paging problem?

Comment: HTML wasn't meant for paged content. The tools that covert to paged convert (for example, for printing) tend to just slice the content into pieces as though it were just one long image. That aside, you might have luck with changing your page layout and taking advantage of rules available in the [CSS Paged Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Pages) module.